# Showing that if $a<b$, then $a^{1/n} < b^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that for $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^+$, if $a<b$, then $a^{1/n} < b^{1/n}$. I'm naturally proceeding by induction on $n$, with it being trivial for $1$. I've proven it separately before with $n=2$ as well, and I'm just gong to assume it true here for convenience. My problem is in the induction step, having it assumed to be true for some fixed $n$. I need to show $a^{1/(n+1)} < b^{1/(n+1)} $. I'm having a complete brain fart. Can anyone help?

Comment: I suggest trying a proof by contradiction: what happens if $b^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq a^{\frac{1}{n}}$?

Comment: I got it now! I actually tried this first and got stuck on an algebra mistake. Just retried it again and realized what I did wrong. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: This is e uivalent to (a^n<b^n implies a<b ) . But it is easily shown that when a<b a^n<b^n and similarly when b<a b^n<a^n . This is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go by induction, prove that the function $x\mapsto x^n$, defined for $x>0$, is increasing (when $n>0$).

The base case is obvious. Suppose that, for $0<x<y$, we have $x^n<y^n$. Then
$$
x^{n+1}=x\cdot x^nx<x\cdot y^n<y\cdot y^n=y^{n+1}
$$

Therefore, $a^{1/n}<b^{1/n}$ is equivalent to $(a^{1/n})^n<(b^{1/n})^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = \sqrt[n]{a}, y = \sqrt[n]{b} \implies x^n = a, y^n = b \implies y^n > x^n \implies y^n - x^n > 0 \implies y - x = \dfrac{y^n-x^n}{y^{n-1}+ y^{n-2}x + ..+ y^{n-k}x^{k-1} + ...+ x^{n-1}}> 0\implies x < y.$