# Prove If $0<x<y$, then $x^{\frac{1}{n}}< y^{\frac{1}{n}},\, n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Graphically I can see that. But i don't know how to prove this.

We have to prove using the fact that $x^n <y^n$

Any help please.

Comment: $x$ raise to $\frac{1}{n}$. $t$ and $s$ are positive.

Comment: Suppose $x^{1/n}\geq y^{1/n}$. Then since the function $a\mapsto a^n$ is increasing for $a\geq0$, we have $x=(x^{1/n})^n\geq(y^{1/n})^n=y$, a contradiction.

Comment: In fact this is just the contrapositive of $x\ge y\implies x^n\ge y^n$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing that if $a<b$, then $a^{1/n} < b^{1/n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845204/showing-that-if-ab-then-a1-n-b1-n)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3887296/42969.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct inequality, using natural logarithm:

$y>x>0$, then

$$\begin{align}\ln y>\ln x
& \iff \frac 1n\ln (y)>\frac 1n\ln ( x)\\
&\iff \ln y^{\frac 1n} >\ln x^{\frac 1n} \\
&\iff y^{\frac 1n}>x^{\frac 1n}.\end{align}$$